# sha1_process macro evaluates to value?

Tags: c, encryption, macros, aes

I'm digging into `sha1.c` and `md5.c` from author Christophe Devine in order to implement AES encryption over the WWW.  Presumably the files are the same on the test server and client.  However, our generated keys are different even though the information used to generate the keys is identical.

The heart of the calculation in both methods is in `xxx_process(...)`.  In both there's a bit of macro magic going on.  I presume if someone is going to take the effort to write a macro, then it should do something.  If someone takes the time to write a macro function that's expression is used as an input to another macro, then I presume it should evaluate to some deterministic value.  That's not what I'm seeing in the call to `P(a,b,c,d,e,x)`, when `R(t)` is passed in for `x`.  Am I reading this incorrectly?  Or does `R(t)` not evaluate to an expression in the following call?

```
P( B, C, D, E, A, R(19) );

#define P(a,b,c,d,e,x)                                  \
{                                                       \
    e += S(a,5) + F(b,c,d) + K + x; b = S(b,30);        \
}

#define R(t)                                            \
(                                                       \
    temp = W[(t -  3) & 0x0F] ^ W[(t - 8) & 0x0F] ^     \
           W[(t - 14) & 0x0F] ^ W[ t      & 0x0F],      \
    ( W[t & 0x0F] = S(temp,1) )                         \
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These macros are bad programming style, but basically the result of an expansion of `R` is an expression, yes. But since this expression depends on `W` it is not a constant expression, if that is what you are looking for.

A more proper implementation would use `inline` functions for both `P` and `R`. E.g for `R`

```
inline
tType R(tType t, WType W[]) {
  tType temp = W[(t -  3) & 0x0F] ^ W[(t - 8) & 0x0F] ^
           W[(t - 14) & 0x0F] ^ W[ t      & 0x0F];
  W[t & 0x0F] = S(temp,1);
}
```

On modern platforms this should result in identical or even better object code. It also has the advantage to be much easier to debug.

The reason to do such things with macros is probably that this is supposed to be compiled by old compilers with less optimization features.

The implementation of `P` is really bad, independently of compiling for oldish compilers or not:

- it replaces a function like call by something that is not an expression or statement, the `do { ... } while(0)` should be used for this
- it evaluates macro parameters in arithmetic expressions without
  surrounding them with `()` which can result in surprising expansions
  if you pass other expression into the macro.